# How to make the covariate in rhohat() a factor?

Tags: r, geospatial, spatial, spatstat

I'm trying to use the rhohat() function to estimate changes and I have my ppp file and image file. When I run the fuction I get this error

> Error in spatialCovariateEvidence.exactppm(model = list(X = list(window = list( :
> Only implemented for multitype models (factor marks)

I have tried using factor(), as.factor() to make my im data a factor but it still doesn't work. I'm not familiar with this so I'd appreciate any assistance.

```
o_longleaf <- subset(longleaf, marks >= 10)
o_longleaf_den <- density(o_longleaf, sigma=bw.diggle(o_longleaf))
plot(o_longleaf_den,main=NULL)
contour(o_longleaf_den,col="green", add=TRUE)

rho_kp <- rhohat(longleaf, o_longleaf_den, method="ratio")

plot(rho_kp, main=NULL)
```

I'm first getting a subset of the data, then I'm using density to estimate the density, this returns an im file. I then put that im file in rhohat. I'm probably doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This is not about the image covariate. The error occurs because the point pattern dataset `longleaf` has numerical marks (giving the diameter of each tree). The function `rhohat` does not handle point patterns with numerical marks.

I will edit the error message so that it is a bit more informative!

You can either remove the marks (which is what I think you want to do) or convert the marks to a factor representing size categories.

To me it would make more sense to do something like

```
 old <- unmark(subset(longleaf, marks > 10))
 young <- unmark(subset(longleaf, marks <= 10))
 Dold <- density(old, bw.diggle)
 f <- rhohat(young, Dold)
```